# How to evaluate multiple expression in if--elif statement in python?

Tags: python, if-statement

How to evaluate multiple expression in if--elif in below code snipet.

I am sure its basic syntax issue

```
n=5
if n%2 != 0:    
    print ("weird")    
elif n%2 == 0 && 2 < n && n <5:    
    print "Not Weird"
elif n%2 == 0 && 6 < n && n < 20:
    print "Weird"
elif n%2 == 0 && n >20:
    print "NOt Weird"
```

Comment: It's `and`, not `&&`.

Comment: I am trying to print some message on the basis of some condition like 
    If n is odd, print Weird
    If n is even and in the inclusive range of to , print Not Weird
    If n is even and in the inclusive range of to , print Weird
    If n is even and greater than , print Not Weird

Comment: You should use "and" operator for multiple possibility

Comment: Also you should use "2<n<5" instead of "2<n and n<5" for better code

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
n = 5

if n % 2:    
    print("weird")    
elif 2 < n < 5:    
    print("Not Weird")
elif 6 < n < 20:
    print("Weird")
elif n > 20:
    print("NOt Weird")
```

Comment: You can squeeze the < tests

Comment: And the == tests are redundant

Comment: @Elazar, thanks for the suggestions. Made changes accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Squeezing the size down a bit:

```
n = 5

if n % 2 != 0:
    print("weird")
else:
    if 2 < n < 5:
        print("Not Weird")
    elif 6 < n < 20:
        print("Weird")
    elif 20 < n:
        print("NOt Weird")
```

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers true, for sure. Yet I still find the above simpler to read. Taking it to the extreme: the elif is also completely useless if you do this: `print("weird" if n % 2 else ("Not Weird" if 2 < n < 5 else ("Weird" if 6 < n < 20 else "Not Weird")))` .. I still prefer the useless nesting, it separates visually well the modulus test from the `in range` tests.

Comment: most pythonistas would disagree (cf Python Zen #4 : Flat is better than nested), and language set aside most programmers (well experienced ones at least) would qualify this as "apprentice level, not yet mastering boolean logic". Not to say you don't (nothing personal here), just that in my team (3 seniors, 1 junior), only the junior would eventually write it this way, and it would be changed to the "flat" variant during the code review, with the reviewer making sure the junior understands the exclusion between the first `if` and the following `elif`s.

Comment: To me it looks just like `if some_expression == True: return True; else: return False` instead of `return someexpression` (or `return bool(someexpression)` if you really want a proper boolean) - both are equivalent, but the first one is obviously beginner's code.

Comment: Haha yeah, I expected #4 to be brought up, but #1 and #3 and #6 can all be brought up here too. If you take `import this` objectively then you're doing it wrong ;) I also lead a team of engineers and I would never accept anything like this either. I'd most definitely extract the hard coded values into some predefined `data_rules`, a la `RANGES = ((2,5,"Not weird"), (6,20,"Weird"), (20, -1, "Not Weird"))` and then use that inside a pure function. This is clearly not production code and it seems obvious that OP is a beginning to learn the basics of bool logic.

Comment: I of course don't take Python's zen as a literal guideline (hopefully xD) - but there's still a lot of wisdom in it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Some points while writing if else:
1. Don't repeat code if a condition is repeating break it into nested if-else.
2. Use `2 < n < 5` rather than `2 < n and n < 5`, write code in pythonic style.
3. use else for default cases, don't put unnecessary conditions.
4. You are using print in 2 different styles, use one.

```
n=5
if n%2 != 0:    
    print("weird")    
else:
    if 2 < n < 5:    
        print("Not Weird")
    elif 6 < n < 20:
        print("Weird")
    else:
        print("NOt Weird")
```

Comment: The nested `else` is totally useless - a elif would be enough

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Replace the `else` with a `elif 2 < n < 5`, indent back all remaining `elif` and the last `else` clause, and you'll get the same results without any nesting, cf srig's answer

Comment: update: for the "flat" version you need a `elif n > 20:` instead of a `else` for the last clause to get the correct result for `n = 0`

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple branch in an if/elif statement that does the same thing you could use the `or` operator.
Something like this might work:

```
n = 5

if n % 2 != 0 or (not n % 2 and 6 < n < 20):    
    print("weird")    
else:    
    print("Not Weird")
```

Comment: Well yeah, but they look like typos and most of the answers correct them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
n = 5

if n%2 != 0:
    print('weird')
elif n%2 == 0 and 2 <= n <= 5:
    print("Not Weird")
elif n%2 == 0 and 6 <= n <= 20:
    print("Weird")
elif n%2 == 0 and n > 20:
    print("Not Weird")
```